# Invalid Command Name whilst sending If Statement

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

new to bash programming,

The following expect script ssh's into a server however is getting an invalid command name error when attempting to send that command. Also, a secondary issue even if the 'if' command works, the following expect line will pick up a 'fail' or 'pass' from the command itself rather than waiting for the result - how do I make it wait for the appropriate result.

```
send "if [[ $(hostname -s) == $hostname ]] ; then echo pass ; else echo fail ; fi ; \r"
        expect {
                "fail" {
                        send -- "echo failed\r"
                }
                "pass" {
                        send -- "echo success\r"
                }
        }
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: What is _a target user_?

Comment: Which _'if' command works_?

Comment: Which is the _invalid command name_?

Comment: Perhaps `expect {
                "fail\r" …` solves the _secondary issue_.

Comment: to write Expect you have to learn Tcl first. e.g. `[ ... ]`, `$(hostname -s)` and `$hostname` all have special meaning in Tcl. if you are more comfortable with shell syntax you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/).

Comment: @Shak : In Tcl, double quotes interpolate the string, which means that any embedded `[......]` will be interpreted as Tcl command. Use `{ .... }`  if you don't want this to happen, instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

expect in an extension of [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) language. Tcl uses `[...]` as its [command substitutio](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M11) syntax.

Assuming you intend to execute `hostname -s` on the remote host, you have to write:

```
send "if \[\[ \$(hostname -s) == $hostname ]] ; then echo pass ; else echo fail ; fi ; \r"

# or, with shell boolean operators
send "\[\[ \$(hostname -s) == $hostname ]] && echo pass || echo fail\r"
```

That protects the open brackets and shell command substitution from Tcl's interpretation, but allows the `$hostname` variable to be expanded.